# Batch file to upload only today's files to S3 (get filenames as list, loop through, execute cp command)

Tags: batch-file, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I need to create a script to copy only the files created today in `Z:\` drive to AWS S3 using `aws s3 cp` command at a scheduler basis.

For example in Z:\, currently I have these files:

```
Filename                                            Date Modified
BELSIZE.0.DB2.NODE0000.CATN0000.20160313090011.001  3/13/2016 9:00 AM
BELSIZE.0.DB2.NODE0000.CATN0000.20160314090015.001  3/14/2016 9:00 AM
BELSIZE.0.DB2.NODE0000.CATN0000.20160315090010.001  3/15/2016 9:00 AM
BELSIZE.0.DB2.NODE0000.CATN0000.20160315100012.001  3/15/2016 10:00 AM
```

I need to copy only the last 2 files dated 3/15/2016 to AWS S3.

What I have now is:

1. List the path + filename created today:

   ```
   forfiles /P "Z:\" /s /m *.* /d +0 /c "cmd /c echo @path
   ```
2. Copy file to AWS S3:

   ```
   aws s3 cp Z:\BELSIZE.0.DB2.NODE0000.CATN0000.20160315090010.001 s3://backup
   ```

I am thinking of getting 1) as a list, loop through 1) and execute 2). How can I do this?

I tried the below command. The file created today doesn't get copied to S3.

```
forfiles /P "Z:\" /s /m *.001 /d +0 /c "cmd /c aws s3 cp @path s3://backup"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy with WinSCP. To upload only today's files, use a batch file like:

```
winscp.com /log=S3.log /ini=nul /command ^
    "open s3://S3KEY:S3SECRET@s3.amazonaws.com/" ^
    "put -filemask=>=today Z:\* /bucket/" ^
    "exit"
```

The [`>=today` keyword](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#today) is supported by WinSCP 5.15 and newer only. In older versions, you can use [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp):

```
    "put -filemask=>=%%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%% Z:\* /bucket/" ^
```

You need to [URL-encode special characters in the credentials](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url#special). WinSCP GUI can [generate an S3 script template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating), like the one above, for you.

Alternatively, since WinSCP 5.19, you can use [`-username`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#username) and [`-password`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#password) switches, which do not need any encoding:

```
    "open s3://s3.amazonaws.com/ -username=S3KEY -password=S3SECRET" ^
```

References:

- [Uploading the most recent file with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_most_recent_file);
- [Time constraints in WinSCP file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time);
- [WinSCP `%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp);
- [Connecting to Amazon S3 with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_s3).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*